# What's wrong in this query

Tags: php

```
if (!empty($_POST['comment']))
 {
       mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET opp=1, SET inforecall='"$_POST['comment']"' WHERE contact_id='"$_GET['id']"' ");

}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with this question

Comment: Please tell us of your error / problem you're encountering.

Comment: SQL Injection vulnerability, for one.

Comment: Aside from your question being vague and your query prone to SQL injection attacks, you have used keyword `SET` twice which makes your query fail.
I suggest trying to get the next answer on your own rather than immediately posting on SO without a single effort on your side to fix the problem. That's NOT the way to learn.

Comment: Did you get a PHP error with this, @marcostT? That looks like it shouldn't even be understood by the compiler. And yes, serious security problems with tainted variables here too. (Downvoted, as posting code without explanation of errors or evidence of prior research).

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is lack of concatenation operators, change:

```
"UPDATE contacts SET opp=1, SET inforecall='"$_POST['comment']"' WHERE contact_id='"$_GET['id']"' ";
```

to:

```
"UPDATE contacts SET opp=1, inforecall='" . $_POST['comment'] . "' WHERE contact_id='" . $_GET['id'] . "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat `SET`. It's just

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1=val1, col2=val2 WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not give multiple `SET` keyword against each fieldname -
The proper code should be:

```
if (!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET opp=1, inforecall='"$_POST['comment']"' WHERE ontact_id='"$_GET['id']"' ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['comment']))
{
       mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET opp=1, inforecall='{$_POST['comment']}' WHERE contact_id='{$_GET['id']}'");
}
```

That should solve your problems. If your `contact_id` is an INT then remove both of the single quotes after its equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you shouldn't have SET twice, just do

```
UPDATE contacts SET opp=1, inforecall=...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are two set in the query, secondly there is an error in the syntax ( the php code $_post and $_get should be concatinated along with rest of the string and there are both get and post method used in the same place which are not sent at the same time.if you use post for both Maybe this will work,

```
if (!empty($_POST['comment']))
 {
       mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET opp=1,inforecall='".$_POST['comment']."' WHERE contact_id='".$_POST['id']."' ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this

```
    if (!empty($_POST['comment']))

    {

    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $comment=$_POST['comment'];

    $query="UPDATE contacts SET opp=1, SET inforecall='$comment' WHERE contact_id='$id'";
               mysql_query($query);
}
```